# Using localstorage, how to save a toggled state in javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, nanogallery

I am using an image gallery plugin, [nanoGallery2](http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/index.html) with a custom button to toggle an icon for an image as a "favorite". I would like to save the toggled state of the icon in localstorage. Since I am obviously clueless on how to get this to work by myself, I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/WjezQM) with my attempt at localstorage. Which is not working.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#nanogallery2").nanogallery2({
thumbnailWidth:             'auto',
thumbnailHeight:            200,
itemsBaseURL:               'http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/samples/',
    locationHash:               false,
thumbnailHoverEffect2 :     '.ngy2info_opacity_0_1|.ngy2info_scale_5_1',
thumbnailBuildInit2:        '.ngy2info_translateY_-50%|.ngy2info_translateX_-50%',
thumbnailToolbarImage:      { topLeft: 'custom1' },
fnThumbnailInit:            myTnInit,
fnThumbnailToolCustAction:  myTnTool,
icons:                      { thumbnailCustomTool1 : '<i class="nGY2Icon icon-heart"></i>'}

});
});

var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites)); 
localStorage.getItem('favorites');


// click/touch on custom tool/button
function myTnTool( action, item ) {
console.dir(item);

switch( action ) {
case 'info':     
  break;
case 'custom1':
  // switch favorite status
  item.customData.favorite=!item.customData.favorite;
  TnSetFavorite(item);

  break;
 }
 }

// Add custom elements after one thumbnail is build
 function myTnInit( $e, item, GOMidx ) { 
  TnSetFavorite( item);

}

// Set the favorite status
function TnSetFavorite(item) {
var c='#fff';
var d='#f90';
if( item.customData.favorite ) {
    item.$elt.find('[data-ngy2action="custom1"]').css('color',d);
 localStorage.setItem(item, 'favorites');
} else {
item.$elt.find('[data-ngy2action="custom1"]').css('color',c);
localStorage.removeItem(item);
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `favorite`? a boolean? a string? a class selector?

Comment: Setting a favorite sets the data-attribute ````data-customData='{ "favorite": false}' ```` to ````data-customData='{ "favorite": true}' ````. See the codepen html

Comment: So...it's a string? What you wrote is: `data-customData = string`

Comment: Your attribute should be `data-custom-data` on the element lowercased. When using JS it should be referred as `customData`. The `data-` prefix is dropped and any other words preceded by a hyphen `-` will be camel cased.

Comment: Attribute has to be customData since that wording  is required by the plugin. Not sure how this relates to the localstorage issue?

Comment: The plugin does not require that you use invalid syntax. The plugin is using correct syntax. `data-ngthumb` instead of `dataNgthumb`

Comment: Well, I actually forked the codepen from the author of the plugin so he must be using invalid syntax. (Actually his documentation says to use ````data-ngcustomData```` but obviously data-customData works as well since he used it in his codepen).  Anyway, I appreciate your comments but my question wasn't about his data attribute syntax (which I updated) but about localstorage.

Comment: it's unfortunate that nanoGallery2 is so poorly documented.